# Chrome Extension - Show an alert on Chrome error page for specific urls

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I would like to show an alert on Chrome's error page(see example at the bottom) when Chrome encounters a specific type of error for a specific url/domain.

I tried the below:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred.addListener(details => {
  if (
    details.error === "net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT" &&
    details.url.includes("ycombinator.com")
  ) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript(
      {
        target: { tabId: details.tabId },
        files: ["alert.js"],
      },
      () => console.log("script executed")
    )
  }
})
```

but it throws an error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-error://chromewebdata/". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

alert.js content

```js
const blocked = () => alert('This website is blocked temporarily');
blocked()
```

In my manifest(v3), I have `webNavigation`, `scripting` and `tabs` in permissions and ["http://*/", "https://*/"] in host_permissions.
I tried adding `"chrome-error://*/"` to host_permissions but that didn't fix the error.

Example error page:
[image: Chrome error page]

Comment: The error page has `chrome-error://` URL. Extensions can't inject code there.

Comment: @wOxxOm Any workarounds or alternate ways to achieve my goal? I tried `chrome.tabs.updatedetails.tabId, {url: chrome.runtime.getURL("redirect.html"),})` inside `onErrorOccurred` but that creates an entry in Chrome history which I don't want.